# How to install lsb-core package on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, 16.04

In order to activate Maple16, I need to install the lsb-core package. However, I cannot find the package in Syanptic Package Manager. I've tried to install it by downloading the .deb file, but when I run `sudo dpkg -i /home/foo/Downloads/lsb-core_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_amd64.deb`, the output of the terminal is

```
(Reading database ... 178439 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-core_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-core (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) over (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-core:
 lsb-core depends on lsb-security (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6); however:
  Package lsb-security is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-core (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lsb-core
```

How can I install this package?

Comment: For me, still on 15.10, `lsb-core` is in the repos. `apt-cache depends lsb-core`
 tells me this package has these dependencies `lsb-release` `libc6` and `libz1`, find and install these too. I can't test it for you, I don't have 16.04.

Comment: Here is `lbs-relese` https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/lsb I think you may only need to install this one.

Comment: @MarkKirby thanks for your answer.  Could you explain me how to install launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/lsb. I've download the file and search Google for the last 30 minutes to try to understand how to install .TAR.xZ files, but apparently that's very difficult if you don't know what you're doing (and I don't know what I'm doing).

Comment: There is a .deb file available, open a terminal and run `wget launchpadlibrarian.net/233789933/lsb-release_9.20160110_all.deb` and it will download to your /home. You can also find it under `Binary packages` on that page but is is a bit tricky to find.

Comment: @MarkKirby thanks for your help. I installed it, but unfortunately I still can't activate Maple. At this point I'm not sure if it's because of the lack of the lsb-core package or if it is some other problem with Maple.

Comment: Try installing this too `wget launchpadlibrarian.net/176607818/lsb-security_4.1+Debian11ubuntu8_amd64.deb` and then tell me if the error message changes

Comment: @MarkKirby still not working unfortunately. I've contacted Maple and see if there is another way to activate Maple, I really hope so because otherwise I will have to go back to Ubuntu 14.04. But again, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Hunter The correct way is to remove the dependency on `lsb-core` and then do a symlink as described here: http://superuser.com/a/1039707/53494. The answer is written for Google Earth but the same reasoning applies to Maple.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`lsb-core` seems to have been re-added to Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) just now.

Answer (score 2):

Out of desperation I've downloaded and installed the lsb-core package for Ubuntu 14.04, [see here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lsb-core), and this works because now I can activate Maple.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04, just `sudo apt-get install lsb-core` worked for me.
To check LSB Version, do `lsb_release`

Comment: Duplicate of this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/793688/790920

Answer (score 0):

With the newest version of Hamachi (2.1.0-165) "[[Hamachi] can now be installed without [the] LSB package.](http://vpn.net/linux)"

Answer (score -1):

FYI, for anyone looking for this with Hamachi (or others): Found this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
```

Comment: -1 This is a terrible idea and asking for trouble. You shouldn't mix package repositories of different Ubuntu releases unless you know what you're doing. There are ways to prevent those issues *and* keep the repository but they're not trivial.

Comment: This is a terrible idea but may be the solution for some situations, e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/767012/epson-printer-with-ubuntu-16-04 If one is going to try this approach it is better to remove the repository once it is done.