# Epson Printer with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing, 16.04, epson

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

not working with Ubuntu 16.04 Epson L130 printer added but with a different driver which is not for inkjet printers or is not working with Epson L130, Now what to do?
N.B. Manual .deb driver install also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a bug for all Epson printers on Ubuntu 16.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lsb/+bug/1576632.

Comment: The fact is my all Epson printers stopped working. Although it looks like not all but some Epson printer working with open driver.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with my epson l355

Here's how i fix it

1. Add ubuntu trusty repository to your source list in "software and updates"

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main`

2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install lsb-core lsb`
4. Remove or deactivate the trusty repository
5. `sudo apt-get update`
6. Install your printer driver .deb via your favorite way

Hope it works...

Sorry for my english

Comment: This works but just remember to remove the trusty repository after lsb install.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing numerous threads and implementing all of the recommended configurations, I was still unable to get xsane to locate a Epson network scanner. I then tried to launch sane from the command line and xsane successfully launched:

xsane epson2:net:192.168.1.10

I changed the shortcut command for xsane to the same and sane now successfully launches and locates the network printer. For some reason, sane does not seem to recognize the setting in net.conf.

Also, the same works for simple-scan:
simple-scan epson2:net:192.168.1.10